# Is it possible to extend a generic class using extension methods?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I would like to build a generic extension method that can be applied to any class but I am not sure how to do this.

So far I have:

```
public static class ClassExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetName(this class tempClass)
    {
        return typeof(tempClass).Name;
    }
}
```

so I could use it as:

```
var NameOfClass1 = MyClass.GetName();
var NameOfClass2 = DiffClass.GetName();
```

But currently this doesn't compile.

Is it possible to do this or do I have to do an extension method on a `Type`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a static extension method and I see no workaround to achieve just what you want.

What's wrong with this?

```
var nameOfClass1 = typeof(MyClass).Name;
```

Is that still too long? No way to make it shorter.

OK, put the extension on `Type` as you cannot extend a `class`. You can only extend on values, not on types.

So your `Type` extension method would be:

```
public static string GetName(this Type type) 
{ 
   return type.Name;
}
```

And you would use it like:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetName();
```

Comment: My example is dumbed down slightly. In actual fact I am getting a SQLite tableName. Which means the extension method would initially try get the name from attributes falling back onto the Name of the class. Can I extend the Type instead?

Comment: @user1 the example is over-over-simplified. `Name` is part of `Type`, thus available to all classes. You wouldn't be able to call any other methods unless you provided type constraints. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: `this Type tempClass` should do. You still need to use `typeof` like `typeof(MyClass).GetName()` anyway.

Comment: @user1 I added some code. What about that? Does that fit your use case?

Comment: @usr Yes that works. Looks like that is the solution. I will edit your answer to add a few more details to make it slightly more useful

Answer (score 1):

Just make the method generic:

```
public static class ClassExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetName<T>(this T tempClass)
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
}
```

This requires you to call the method on an  instance of T.
But your case is not a very good example, since you can just call `.Name` on a Type directly; no need for an extension method.
If you want to constrain T to classes only, you can add `where T : class`:

```
public static string GetName<T>(this T tempClass) where T : class
{
    return typeof(T).Name;
}
```

Comment: where would I add the `T contraint?`

Comment: I've tried this method. I'm not sure it works.. `MyClass.GetName()` isnt available on my class. Have you managed to get this working? It only works for instances of the object rather than the object

Comment: @user1 Because you cannot write extension method on Types, only on instances. You must call it on an instance, so you can't say `MyClass.GetName()`, only `MyClass instance = new MyClass(); instance.GetName();`